# remove the by default background of Mui tooltip and customize in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, tooltip

Here I have written a tooltip, one is taking the default background, and in the nested tooltip I need to customise the background. I also did that with a white background and black text, but you can observe the grey border is still there in the customise tooltip. So how can I remove that and create a fully customizable background for the mui tooltip? I need only white background and black color in the customize tooltip The code is given below.

```
import React from "react";
import { Tooltip } from "@mui/material";
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  customTooltip: {
    background: "white",
    color: "black",
    margin: "0px",
    whiteSpace: "normal",
    maxWidth: "40px"
  }
});

const CustomTooltip = ({ title, children }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Tooltip title={title} placement="bottom-start">
      <div>
        {children}
        <Tooltip
          title={
            <p
              className={classes.customTooltip}
            >
              {"Nested Tooltip"}
            </p>
          }
          placement="bottom-start"
        >
          <div>icon</div>
        </Tooltip>
      </div>
    </Tooltip>
  );
};

const App = () => (
  <CustomTooltip title="Outer Tooltip">
    <div>Hover Me</div>
  </CustomTooltip>
);

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

When using the custom style in your component, pass the custom `classes.customTooltip` to the `classes` prop of the `Tooltip` component.

Like this:

```
<Tooltip
  title="Nested Tooltip"
  placement="bottom-start"
  classes={{ tooltip: classes.customTooltip }}
>
  <div>icon</div>
</Tooltip>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not use makeStyles as its deprecated now in MUI v5.
Theirs few other way to make custom components such as styled components in MUI.
Here's one example from Docs:

```
 const LightTooltip = styled(({ className, ...props }: TooltipProps) => (
  <Tooltip {...props} arrow classes={{ popper: className }} />
))(({ theme }) => ({
  [`& .${tooltipClasses.tooltip}`]: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.white,
    color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87)",
    boxShadow: theme.shadows[1],
    fontSize: 11,
  },
  [`& .${tooltipClasses.arrow}`]: {
    color: theme.palette.common.white,
  },
}));
```

and this is being called:

```
  <LightTooltip title="Tooltip" placement="bottom">
    <Button>Something</Button>
  </LightTooltip>
```